# How to pass a property to the index file in polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a web component where I obtain a string from firebase, and I want to use that string in the index page but I don't know how to obtain that value to use it in my index file. I call my web component like this:

```
<template id="app" is="dom-bind">        
   <sel-edo-autonomo myPropertie="{{I_want_here_the_value_of_the propertie}}">
   </sel-edo-autonomo>

    <paper-input label="the value of the propertie is:" id="campoPais">{{myPropertie}}</paper-input>
</template>
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. By selecting the `dom-bind` template in JavaScript and then accessing the property you want on like so:

```
<template id="app" is="dom-bind">        
   <sel-edo-autonomo myPropertie="{{I_want_here_the_value_of_the propertie}}">
   </sel-edo-autonomo>

    <paper-input label="the value of the propertie is:" id="campoPais">{{myPropertie}}</paper-input>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = document.querySelector("#app");
  var myVar = app.myPropertie;
</script>
```

There is some basic info on the auto-binding templates [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind)